# Code works only when i use print() in pygame library

Tags: python, pygame

This chunk of code only works when i declare the print("abc"), otherwise it just won't work at all for no aparent reason
Im using pygame for a Minesweeper project that im doing

works:

```
for Sprite in self.CellsSprites:
    if Sprite.rect.colliderect(self.rect):
        print("abc")
        if time.time() - self.time > 0.1 and self.block == False:
            self.block = True
            self.time = time.time()
            Cell_Hold((Sprite.rect.x,Sprite.rect.y),{self.CellsSprites})
            break
```

doesn't work:

```
for Sprite in self.CellsSprites:
    if Sprite.rect.colliderect(self.rect):
        if time.time() - self.time > 0.1 and self.block == False:
            self.block = True
            self.time = time.time()
            Cell_Hold((Sprite.rect.x,Sprite.rect.y),{self.CellsSprites})
            break
```

What this does is that it looks for every sprite that collides with another one and draws another sprite on top of it

Answer (score 1):

`time.time() - self.time > 0.1`

Maybe the `print("abc")` line slows the execution time just enough for this if clause to be true? Whereas without the print line, the code runs too fast so that this clause is false? Try lowering the float number a bit and see if you notice a difference. Or else pause the execution for a millisecond in place of the print statement?

EDIT: Adding a useful suggestion into this answer, provided by @Jskkc who commented below, use `pygame.time.Clock()` to limit the frame rate - this is a much better way than artificially limiting the update with the clumsy if block, which as you found out is affected by whatever code may or may not have been executed beforehand.

Comment: lol i though that it wouldnt work but it actually did!
that line is actually to slow down the code since it would draw hundreds of sprites per second and my vsc would crash.
ty a lot!

Comment: No problem - I looked at your code a few times and that's the only conclusion I could draw that made sense of why it didn't work without the print!

Comment: @Jskkc you can use a [`pygame.time.Clock()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/time.html#pygame.time.Clock.tick) to limit the frame rate.